# entity framework 5 onObjectMaterialized missing?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I searched for onObjectMaterialized that I used in EF 4 to have code run as soon as an entity is materialized.  But only found 3 answers and none really help.

In EF4, I remember editing the VS.NET EF templates, then updating VS.NET to use those new template that cause the ObjectContext to enable support.

But with EF 5, I now have a DBContext and can't seem to find out how to do the same thing.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Perhaps there is a better way to do what you want?  Are you trying to initialize the objects?

Comment: I have a "packed field" that I need to unpack.  I don't have control over the database or structures. With EF5, I have to materialize the entity, then call an unpack method.  An alt is to add a check to all gets to unpack if necessary - but that's lots of repetitive code.

Comment: You can always use the Object context adapter.  Something like this '((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += 
    this.ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An even better solution was to just eliminate the whole edmx thing and use the reverse code first approach.  This ended up being much more efficient and I didn't have to play games with the xml in the edmx.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  Mystere Man, I have an answer.  And it's much easier than I thought.

Others may have a different approach, but the key info is the same.

Create a partial class for your context.  This isn't required, but it helps isolate your code from generated code.

Under the xxxModel.edmx in the solution should be 4 separate files.  Open the one that ends in .tt.  This is the template.

In the template, add a call to a method after the template code to create the constructor.  The template code should look similar to this:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
    {
        public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
            : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
        {
            // Put your method call here 
            MyConstructor();
```

Now, in your partial class (or the template if you don't use partial classes), define the method and add the code from Mystere Man.

```
protected void MyConstructor()
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += this.ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized;
    }
```

Then you just add your method to fire:

```
public void ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized(Object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Entity is IMyEntityClass) .....
```

or whatever you want to have happen when an entity is materialzed.  In my case, I just check if the entity is the type that holds the packed field and, if so, call the code to unpack it (which is in a partial class of the entity.)

Enjoy